# Declare a const array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, constants, readonly

Is it possible to write something similar to the following?

```
public const string[] Titles = { "German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" };
```

Comment: static could be used, public static string[] Titles = new string[] { "German", "Spanish"};

Answer (score 951, accepted):

Yes, but you need to declare it `readonly` instead of `const`:

```
public static readonly string[] Titles = { "German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" };
```

The reason is that `const` can only be applied to a field whose value is known at compile-time. The array initializer you've shown is not a constant expression in C#, so it produces a compiler error.

Declaring it `readonly` solves that problem because the value is not initialized until run-time (although it's guaranteed to have initialized before the first time that the array is used).

Depending on what it is that you ultimately want to achieve, you might also consider declaring an enum:

```
public enum Titles { German, Spanish, Corrects, Wrongs };
```

Comment: Note that the *array* here isn't readonly, of course; Titles[2]="Welsh"; would work just fine at runtime

Comment: You probably want it static too

Comment: how about declaring a "const" array in a method body, not in the class one?

Comment: This won't help when you ABSOLUTELY need a const, such as with switch statement cases.

Comment: and const is only for primitive types

Comment: Why can you declare a `string` as const if a string is just a `char[]`?

Comment: string isn't a char[], see [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs). Strings can be consts in C# because the compiler will replace all references to the const with the actual string literal itself.

Answer (score 93):

You can't create a 'const' array because arrays are objects and can only be
created at runtime and const entities are resolved at compile time.

What you can do instead is to declare your array as "readonly". This has the
same effect as const except the value can be set at runtime. It can only be
set once and it is thereafter a readonly (i.e. const) value.

Comment: This post highlights why arrays cannot be declared as constants

Comment: It is possible to declare a constant array; the problem is initializing it with a constant value. The only working example that comes to mind is `const int[] a = null;` which is not very useful, but indeed an instance of an array constant.

Answer (score 77):

**This is the only correct answer. You cannot currently do this.**

All the other answers are suggesting using static read-only variables which are *similar to, but not the same as* a constant. A constant is hard coded into the assembly. A static read-only variable is settable once, probably as an object is initialized.

These are sometimes interchangeable, but not always.

*EDIT*: I thought I'd throw this in, as it seems like the person who asked the question was a little fuzzy about arrays. When you declare an array, it is a pointer to a segment of memory that contains the array. It is very simple in that it is just an address, with no complex logic controlling if it is readable or writable. It gives you a pointer, and you can do whatever you want with it.

This is part of the reason why it is a little tricky to make an immutable array. You could write a class that wraps the array and only allows reading of it by returning a copy, but then it really isn't just an array anymore, it is an object that wraps an array.

Some people have suggested using static, or read-only, to simulate the behavior you would see if you could create a const array. These have some side effects that might not be obvious to the casual reader. Also, if you mark an array with read-only, you are marking the pointer to the array, not the array itself. You can change the contents of the array as much as you want:

```
public class Demo
{
    private readonly int[] _foo = new int[] {0,1,2,3};
    
    public void ChangeArray()
    {
        _foo[1] = 42; // works
        _foo = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5 }; // won't even compile
    }
}
```

To truly get a const array, there would need to be an update to C# and the MSIL underlying code to allow reading from an array, but no writing. The other proposals on this page are various creative ways to work around this problem.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering why the most upvoted solutions weren't working for default parameters.

Comment: one thing you *can* do to make it truly* read only is `IEnumerable<int> _foo = new int[] {0,1,2,3}.AsEnumerable();`

*not truly but virtually

Answer (score 72):

You can declare array as `readonly`, but keep in mind that you can change element of `readonly` array.

```
public readonly string[] Titles = { "German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" };
...
Titles[0] = "bla";
```

Consider using enum, as Cody suggested, or IList.

```
public readonly IList<string> ITitles = new List<string> {"German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" }.AsReadOnly();
```

Comment: In .NET 4.5 and higher you can declare a list as IReadOnlyList<string> instead of IList<string>.

Comment: Just to be clear, you can still change the values in an IReadOnlyList (just not add or remove elements).  But yes, declaring it as an IReadOnlyList would be better than an IList.

Answer (score 28):

Since C# 6 you can write it like:

```
public static string[] Titles => new string[] { "German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" };
```

See also: [C# : The New and Improved C# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) (specifically the chapter "Expression Bodied Functions and Properties")

This will make a read-only static property, but it will still allow you to alter the content of the array returned, but when you call the property again, you will get the original, unaltered array again.

For clarification, this code is the same as (or actually a shorthand for):

```
public static string[] Titles
{
    get { return new string[] { "German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" }; }
}
```

Please note that there is a downside to this approach: A new array is actually instantiated on each and every reference, so if you are using a very large array, this might not be the most efficient solution.
But if you re-use the same array (by putting it in a private attribute for instance) it will again open up the possibility to change the contents of the array.

If you want to have an immutable array (or list) you could also use:

```
public static IReadOnlyList<string> Titles { get; } = new string[] { "German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" };
```

But, this still has a risk for changes, as you can still cast it back to a string[] and alter the contents, as such:

```
((string[]) Titles)[1] = "French";
```

Comment: What is the profit of using property instead of field in this case?

Comment: A field cannot return a new object on each call. A property is basically a sort of "function in disguise".

Comment: If you were referring to the last option, that can be done using both a field or a property, but since it is public, I prefer a Property. I never use a public field since the introduction of Properties.

Comment: There is another downside to the 1st approach: you won't get a compilation error if you assign to `Titles[0]`, for instance - in effect, the assignment attempt is quietly ignored. Combined with the inefficiency of recreating the array every time, I wonder if this approach is even worth showing. By contrast, the 2nd approach is efficient, and you have to go out of your way to defeat the immutability.

Answer (score 15):

For the sake of completeness, now we also have [`ImmutableArray`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable) at our disposal. This should be truly immutable:

```
public readonly static ImmutableArray<string> Titles =
    ImmutableArray.Create(new[] { "German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" });
```

Requires `System.Collections.Immutable` NuGet reference.

Comment: I'm not sure when this was added, but `ImmutableArray.Create` takes in `params T[]?`, so the code can be simplified to: `ImmutableArray.Create("German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs")`.

Answer (score 13):

You could take a different approach: define a constant string to represent your array and then split the string into an array when you need it, e.g.

```
const string DefaultDistances = "5,10,15,20,25,30,40,50";
public static readonly string[] distances = DefaultDistances.Split(',');
```

This approach gives you a constant which can be stored in configuration and converted to an array when needed.

Comment: I think the cost of performing the split far outstrips any benefits made by defining const. But +1 for a unique approach and thinking outside the box! ;)

Comment: I was about to post the same solution and then saw this, contrary to the harsh and negative remarks, this was actually perfect for my scenario, where i needed to pass a const to an Attribute, and then i split the value in attribute constructor to get what i needed. and i see no reason why it will have performance cost since attributes are not created for each instance.

Answer (score 13):

A **.NET Framework v4.5+ solution** that improves on [tdbeckett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25211653/45375):

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

// ...

public ReadOnlyCollection<string> Titles { get; } = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(
  new string[] { "German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" }
);
```

<sup>Note: Given that the collection is conceptually constant, it may make sense to make it `static` to declare it at the *class* level.</sup>

The above:

- **Initializes the property's implicit backing field *once*** with the array.

  - Note that `{ get; }` - i.e., declaring only a property *getter* - is what makes the property itself implicitly read-only (trying to combine `readonly` with `{ get; }` is actually a syntax error).
  - Alternatively, you could just omit the `{ get; }` and add `readonly` to create a *field* instead of a property, as in the question, but exposing *public* data members as properties rather than fields is a good habit to form.
- Creates an **array-*like* structure** (allowing *indexed access*) that is **truly and robustly read-only** (conceptually constant, once created), both with respect to:

  - **preventing modification of the collection *as a whole*** (such as by removing or adding elements, or by assigning a new collection to the variable).
  - **preventing modification of *individual elements***.
    (Even *indirect* modification isn't possible - unlike with an **`IReadOnlyList<T>`** solution, where **a `(string[])` cast can be used to gain write access to the elements**, as shown in [mjepsen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38844044/45375).
    The same vulnerability applies to **the `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` *interface***, which, despite the similarity in name to *class* `ReadOnlyCollection`, **does not even support *indexed* access**, making it fundamentally unsuitable for providing array-like access.)

Comment: @mortb: Unfortunately, `IReadOnlyCollection` doesn't support indexed access, so it can't be used here. Additionally, like `IReadOnlyList` (which does have indexed access) it is susceptible to element manipulation by casting back to `string[]`. In other words: `ReadOnlyCollection` (which you cannot cast a string array to) is the most robust solution. Not using a getter is an option (and I've updated the answer to note that), but with _public_ data it's probably better to stick with a property.

Answer (score 11):

If you declare an array behind an IReadOnlyList interface you get a constant array with constant values that is declared at runtime:

```
public readonly IReadOnlyList<string> Titles = new [] {"German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" };
```

Available in .NET 4.5 and higher.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can only make it readonly.

Answer (score 5):

For my needs I define `static` array, instead of impossible `const` and it works:
`public static string[] Titles = { "German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" };`

Comment: Simply removing `const` from OP example also works, but that (or your answer) allows to change both: `Titles` instance and any value. So what is the point in this answer?

Comment: @Sinatr, I answered this 3 years ago, when I strted working in C#. I left it, now I'm in Java world. Perhaps I forgot to add `readonly`

Comment: After second thought, your answer is a direct *how to make OP code working*, without any `const`/`readonly` considerations, simply *making it working* (like if `const` was a syntax mistake). For some people it seems to be a *valuable* answer (perhaps they also tried to use [`const`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) by mistake?).

Answer (score 5):

This is a way to do what you want:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public ReadOnlyCollection<string> Titles { get { return new List<string> { "German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" }.AsReadOnly();}}
```

It is very similar to doing a readonly array.

Comment: You can just do that as `public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<String> Titles = new List<String> { "German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" }.AsReadOnly();`; no need to recreate the list on every retrieve if you make it a ReadOnlyCollection anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are probably one of those things that can only be evaluated at
runtime. Constants must be evaluated at compile time. Try using "readonly"
instead of "const".

Answer (score 2):

Best alternative:

```
public static readonly byte[] ZeroHash = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick workaround in case it's helpful for someone.  I needed a `string[]` to be an argument for an Attribute (passing inline data for a test case in some theory).  `readonly` won't help here.  But, I ended up doing:

```cs
const string foo = "a|b|c";

[InlineData(foo)]
public void Test(string fooString)
{
    var foo = fooString.Split("|"); // foo == {"a","b","c"}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, to get around the elements-can-be-modified issue with a readonly array, you can use a static property instead. (The individual elements can still be changed, but these changes will only be made on the local copy of the array.)

```
public static string[] Titles 
{
    get
    {
        return new string[] { "German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs"};
    }
}
```

Of course, this will not be particularly efficient as a new string array is created each time.