# Const array of strings

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Declare a Const Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142349/declare-a-const-array)

I need an array of const strings in the class. Something like

```
public class some_class_t
{
    public const string[] names = new string[4]
    {
        "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"
    };
}
```

But this code causes an error:

> A constant 'names' of reference type 'string[]' can only be initialized with null.

What should I do?

Comment: Arrays are mutable. They can't be constant unless they're null.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Declare it as `readonly` instead of `const`:

```
public readonly string[] names = { "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta" };
```

Comment: more details available at [http://stackoverflow.com/a/5142378/1080355](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5142378/1080355)

Comment: And declare it `static` so I would use `public readonly string[] names = { "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta" };`

Comment: What mike nelson meant to type was "public static readonly string[] names = { "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta" };

Comment: Why is this accepted? while question was about `const` not `readonly`...

Comment: Because it does what the OP intended (supposedly). You have to have the ability to recognize that, especially as a developer.

Comment: Anyone know how you could actually do it as a const? rather than a readonly? I would like to reference it from my own custom attribute on a class property, and only a const will do. Thanks

Comment: Link for "Since C# 6 you can write it like:  public static string[] Titles => new string[] { "German", "Spanish", "Corrects", "Wrongs" }; " https://stackoverflow.com/a/38844044/2641380