# NUnit Sequential Attribute with arrays in Values

Tags: c#, arrays, nunit, sequential

How I can pass `string[][]` arrays to ValuesAttribute?

I have:

```
public string[][] Array1 = new[] {new[] {"test1", "test2"}};
//...
[Test, Sequential]
public void SomeTest(
    [Values("val1", "val2", "val3")] string param1, 
    [Values(Array1, Array2, Array3)] string[][] param2) { //... }
```

And I've got `Cannot access non-static field "Array1" in static context`. Than I mark `Array1` with `static` keyword and than I've got `An attribute argument must be a constant expression...` than I mark it with `readonly` keyword and still I have `An attribute argument must be a constant expression...`

Is here any way to pass multiple arrays? (Except ugly `string[][][]` and passing `param2` indexes of relevant `array[][]` in `array[][][]`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. But you need to use [TestCaseSourceAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.2) instead of `Sequential` and `Values`.

See an example:

```
object[][] testCases = new[] {

    // test case 1
    new object[] {
        "val1",
        new[] { "test11", "test12" }
    },

    // test case 2
    new object[] {
        "val2",
        new[] { "test21", "test22" }
    },

    // test case 3
    new object[] {
        "val3",
        new[] { "test31", "test32", "test33", "test34" }
    }
};

[Test]
[TestCaseSource("testCases")]
public void SomeTest(string param1, string[] param2)
{
    ...
}
```

Another benefits here: test cases are better organised and they can be easily reused in multiple tests.

Comment: Thank you, that works for me, but is here any way to pass string[][] arrays to ValuesAttribute?

Comment: Don't think it is possible, as attributes accept constant only parameters. But `Array` cannot be declared as constant. See e.g. this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142349/declare-a-const-array