# Using the 'TestCase' attribute with a two-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, nunit, testcaseattribute

I'm using NUnit and trying to implement tests for the following method:
It should accept two integers and returns two dimensional array.
So, header of my test looks like:

```
[TestCase(5, 1, new int[,]{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}})]
public void MyTestMethod(int a, int b, int[][] r)
```

During compilation I've got the following error:

> Error CS0182: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type (CS0182)

---

I know it can be done using `TestCaseSource` to refer to object arrays like the answers to the following questions:

- [How do I put new List {1} in an NUNIT TestCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479817/how-do-i-put-new-listint-1-in-an-nunit-testcase)
- [NUnit Sequential Attribute with arrays in Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171321/nunit-sequential-attribute-with-arrays-in-values)

which gives code like:

```
private object[][] combination_tests =  new [] {
    new object[] {5, 1, new [,]{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}},
};

[Test]
[TestCaseSource("combination_tests")]
public void MyTestMethod(int a, int b, int[,] r)
```

but I still have the question: is it possible to do that with using only the `TestCase` attribute?

Comment: (Summary of existing answers) It is a limitation of the .NET attributes system, so it is not an NUnit defect. Therefore, to workaround the limitation, the data has to be (1) reformatted into a data type that is allowed by .NET attribute system, or (2) stored in a class field, property, or a method that can create and return the data when NUnit loads the unit test project. Other .NET unit testing frameworks will have the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Is it **absolutely** necessary for you to have the same signature for your method, i.e.

```
public void MyTestMethod(int a, int b, int[][] r)
{
    // elided
}
```

Depending on your situation, you have two options available, both of which use the [`[TestCase]`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.6.3) attribute as you said you wanted in the question:

> is it possible to do that with using only the `TestCase` attribute?

I prefer the first option as it feels more concise, but both will suit your needs.

---

**Option 1: If it is NOT necessary to keep the same signature**

You could *modify* the signature slightly so that instead of an array (not compile-time constant), you pass in a string ([which is compile-time constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b)) which can be used to *obtain* the array instead, e.g.

```
private static int[][] getArrayForMyTestMethod(string key)
{
    // logic to get from key to int[][]
}

[TestCase(5, 1, "dataset1")]
public void MyTestMethod(int a, int b, string rKey)
{
    int[][] r = getArrayForMyTestMethod(rKey);
    // elided
}
```

---

**Option 2: If it IS necessary to keep the same signature**

If it is necessary to keep the same signature for the method, you could have a wrapper method that does the same as option 1, i.e.

```
private static int[][] getArrayForMyTestMethod(string key)
{
    // logic to get from key to int[][]
}

[TestCase(5, 1, "dataset1")]
public void MyTestMethodWrapper(int a, int b, string rKey)
{
    int[][] r = getArrayForMyTestMethod(rKey);
    MyTestMethod(a, b, r);
}

public void MyTestMethod(int a, int b, int[][] r)
{
    // elided
}
```

---

Obviously you could use any type which can be compile-time constant instead of a `string` depending on the way your test cases are constructed, but I suggested a `string` because you'd be able to give a *name* to your test case in the NUnit runner that way.

---

Otherwise your alternative is to use [`[TestCaseSource]`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.3) as you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `TestCaseData` object to pass the results in:

```
public IEnumerable<TestCaseData> combination_tests()
{
    yield return new TestCaseData(5,1,new int[,] {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}});
}

[Test]
[TestCaseSource("combination_tests")]
public void test(int a, int b, int[,] r)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r[0,0] & r[1,0]);
}
```

You can also set the test category and test name for each testCaseData item  using `.SetName("xxx")` or `.SetCategory("xxx")` which can be nice for organizing the tests.