# Array error reference error in asmx project

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a very mysterious behavior.

In my C# ASP.NET project (`.asmx` web service), constants are assigned in a file `Constants.cs`.

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyConstants
    {
        public const string MyString = "Mars";
        public static readonly string[] MyArray = { "Pluto", "Eart", "Venus" };
    }
}
```

If `MyString` is called in main unit with

```
string StrPlanet = MyConstants.MyString;
```

all works.

If I call ANY element of `MyArray` and assign it with

```
string StrPlanet = MyConstants.MyArray[0];
```

I get this error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
> at MyProject.Constants..cctor()

Where is mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at the answers to [Declare a const array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142349/declare-a-const-array) and see if any of them provide a good solution for you.

Comment: The above code seems to work fine. Are you sure you are not looping over the `MyConstants.MyArray`? Maybe your index is going out of bounds there.

Comment: Same code in other project works fine. It is very mystery for me.

Comment: "Same code in other project works fine." - So the code works for you?

Comment: @NicoBlu Where is `MyProject.Constants..cctor()` ?

Answer (score -1):

Try making the class `static`: `public static class MyConstants`

Also You could try to use `List<string>` instead.

Comment: Same code works in other twin project... incredibile!

Comment: but I bet it not in a asmx class - which is static by default......